How to get IOPS of docker containers
I try to get information about disk utilization by docker conteiners. I need to know IOPS of containers.
I tried
docker stats

but there i have only Block I/O.
Also i tried
docker system df

but there no IOPS too.
Maybe I can get IOPS by Block I + Block O, but I don't know how to check the time.
